# Chrome blocking my paypal button

Tags: google-chrome, paypal, popup, popupwindow

Installed a paypal button on my landing page but Chrome's seeing a popup and blocking it. Not ideal for people who actually want to pay.

You can reproduce the problem here: https://snapstories.leadpages.co/paypal-button-test/

Any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally if you want a popup based experience with paypal, you should use the checkout.js javascript integration:

https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/add-paypal-button/